# Unexpected value for path in SVG according to console, but it works

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg

I have a HSL colour wheel demo for my students [here](http://itpastorn.github.com/webbteknik/future-stuff/svg/color-wheel.html).

It works, but in the console in Firefox I see an error message:

```
Unexpected value M 0 0 v -15 A 15 15 1 0 1 9.959 -11.217 z) parsing attribute d.
```

Why is this "unexpected" and what can I do about it?

Complete code [here](https://github.com/itpastorn/webbteknik/blob/master/future-stuff/svg/color-wheel.html).

Comment: Perhaps the closing parenthesis shouldn't be there. It doesn't close anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closing bracket ) is the problem. The rule in parsing paths, though is to display up to the point you find an error. The error is in the last character so the path displays just as it would if the error was not present.